# JQuery unwrap ol inside li

Tags: jquery, dom

I've got a little problem with the function unwrap in the following situation:

```
<li id="menu_89">
    <div class="list-item">Home
        <div class="actions"><a class="delete" href="#">Delete</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ol>
        <li id="menu_91">
            <div class="list-item">New user
                <div class="actions"><a class="delete" href="#">Delete</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ol>
                <li id="menu_93">
                    <div class="list-item">Pay
                        <div class="actions"><a class="delete" href="#">Delete</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</li>
```

When pressed on the delete button the list item should be removed and everything between the `<ol>` should stay, but the `<ol>` tags should also be removed. I can't get this done.

so when you press the delete button on Home, home should be deleted and new user and Pay should stay.

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: Where's your code? You mention `unwrap` and so I was expecting to see it used somewhere. (It's not what you'd want for this, I'm just saying...)

Comment: If he's wanting to keep the inner HTML of an element, and remove the container tag, it's exactly what he'd want.

Comment: Sorry forget to add the code I tried, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for your scenario (I'm not sure if it could be optimised further for efficiency):

```
$('#menu_89').on('click', '.delete', function() {
  var $ele = $(this).closest("li").find("ol").eq(0);
   $ele.contents().unwrap();
   $(this).parent().parent().remove(); 
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6JPzb/